# Delete sitecore item from solr index without publishing parent item

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore9

I came across business requirement where I want to delete item from master & web and also delete respective item from solr indexes. business don't want to publish parent item as there might be change i  sibling or parent so I cant trigger any strategy like a **onPublishEndAsync** ,
**onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance**
**onPublishEndAsyncPreview** here I am trying something like below but it is not working

```
    var ParentItem = item.Parent;
                using (new EditContext(item))
                {
                    if (Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.RecycleBinActive)
                        item.Recycle();
                    else
                        item.Delete();
                }
                   if (item == null)
                return;
            ISearchIndex index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex((SitecoreIndexableItem)ParentItem );
            if (index == null)
                return;
            index.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(ParentItem )); or 
           index.RefreshAsync(new SitecoreIndexableItem(item), IndexingOptions.ForcedIndexing, new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
```

I am not getting any error in sitecore log or solr log files but index is not deleting item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mark your item as unpublishable, publish it (that will remove the item from `web` database and from `web` index) and then delete it.

Here is sample code which unpublished item from all publishing target databases:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    var targets = PublishManager.GetPublishingTargets(item.Database)
        .Select(i => Database.GetDatabase(i[FieldIDs.PublishingTargetDatabase]))
        .ToArray();

    var languages = LanguageManager.GetLanguages(item.Database).ToArray();

    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item.Publishing.NeverPublish = true;
    item.Editing.EndEdit();

    var handle = PublishManager.PublishItem(item, targets, languages, false, false);
    PublishManager.WaitFor(handle);
}
```

Just execute `item.Recycle` or `Delete` after.

Some time ago I wrote a blog post describing how to add a ribbon button which will "Delete and Unpublish" item with one click. You can find it here:

[Automatically unpublish deleted Sitecore item](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unpublish-and-delete-item)

Comment: Excellent Marek! As usual you have given very perfect solution. Business really happy with this. I also explain business they can achieve this by existing delete but they need to  set publication restriction as you mansion. I also reached out sitecore ad they confirmed that re-index tree not supporting on WEB DB.

Comment: @SunilAher I'm glad I could help. You may also want to read how to create a custom ribbon button which will unpublish and delete item with one click: https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-unpublish-and-delete-item